# Filtering unix timestamps

Tags: javascript, date, unix

So, I am working on a time registration management tool. I have a date picker component where I choose the date I want to see the registrations from. It gives me the **Unix timestamp of that day** and I store that value, **fx. 1606856503**.

Now, I am retrieving all registrations from the API, which is an array of objects where each object is a registration. Each registration has a date property, which is basically a Unix timestamp from the date it was created.

```
[{
"id": "1",
"userId": "userId 1",
"customerId": "customerId 1",
"case": "case 1",
"description": "description 1",
"hours": 72,
"date": 1606826246,
"customer": "customer 1",
"project": "project 1"
}]
```

Now, that I have a date picker Unix timestamp, I would like to filter the registrations in order to filter and display only registrations which were made on the day of the **Unix timestamp from the picker**, but can't figure out how would I compare them and filter based on the day.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid epoch timestamp

Comment: You can simply convert both to a `Date` object and compare as needed (`.getUTCDate` comes to mind). `new Date(registration.date*1000)` (javascript uses milliseconds whereas unix uses seconds)

Comment: Do you want local date or UTC date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick snippet illustrating using either [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) or [`Date.prototype.toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) to filter against a specified timestamp.

Since your timestamps are stored in seconds and javascript dates use milliseconds, you need to multiply by 1000 when creating your dates

```
const filterTimestamp = 1606859476; // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 9:51:16 PM
const filterDate = new Date(filterTimestamp*1000);
```

You can then filter by comparing the first 10 characters of the date strings returned by `toISOString()` which will always keep the timezone as zero UTC offset

```
const filterDateString = new Date(filterTimestamp*1000).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
// "2020-12-01" sliced from "2020-12-01T21:51:16.000Z"

const regsOnDate = regs.filter(o => (
  new Date(o.date*1000).toISOString().slice(0, 10) === filterDateString));
```

or by the date strings returned by `toDateString()` which will use the local timezone

```
const filterDateString = new Date(filterTimestamp*1000).toDateString();
const regsOnDate = regs.filter(o => (
  new Date(o.date*1000).toDateString() === filterDateString));

// eg: compares "Mon Nov 02 2020" to "Tue Dec 01 2020"
```

---

**Using `toISOString()`**

```js
const regs = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": 1606826246, // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 12:37:26 PM
    "customer": "customer 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": 1604353553, // Monday, November 2, 2020 9:45:53 PM
    "customer": "customer 2",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "date": 1606860022, // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 10:00:22 PM
    "customer": "customer 3",
  }
]

const filterTimestamp = 1606859476; // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 9:51:16 PM
const filterDateString = new Date(filterTimestamp*1000).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
// "2020-12-01" sliced from "2020-12-01T21:51:16.000Z"

const regsOnDate = regs.filter(o => (
  new Date(o.date*1000).toISOString().slice(0, 10) === filterDateString));

console.log( regsOnDate );
```

---

**Using `toDateString()`**

```js
const regs = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": 1606826246, // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 12:37:26 PM
    "customer": "customer 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": 1604353553, // Monday, November 2, 2020 9:45:53 PM
    "customer": "customer 2",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "date": 1606860022, // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 10:00:22 PM
    "customer": "customer 3",
  }
]


const filterTimestamp = 1606859476; // Tuesday, December 1, 2020 9:51:16 PM
const filterDateString = new Date(filterTimestamp*1000).toDateString();

const regsOnDate = regs.filter(o => (
  new Date(o.date*1000).toDateString() === filterDateString));

console.log( regsOnDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamps are seconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC, ECMAScript time values are milliseconds since the same epoch, see [*Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript).

If you just want to compare values for the same date UTC, you can just compare whole days since the epoch. That means a simple arithmetic operation on the value rather than using Date objects. e.g.

```js
let data = [{"id": "1","date": 1606826246}, // 1 Dec 2020 UTC
            {"id": "2","date": 1606867200}, // 2 Dec 2020 UTC
            {"id": "3","date": 1606953600}  // 3 Dec 2020 UTC
  ];

// Start with date sometime on 2 Dec 2020 UTC
let d = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,11,2,8,32,21)); // 2 Dec 2020 08:32:21 Z
console.log('Test date: ' + d.toISOString());

// Get whole days since epoch
let daysSinceEpoch = d.getTime() / 8.64e7 | 0;
console.log('daysSinceEpoch: ' + daysSinceEpoch);

// Find matching records in data
let result = data.filter(obj => (obj.date / 8.64e4 | 0) == daysSinceEpoch);
console.log('Matching records: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

// Matching date values
console.log('Matching dates:');
result.forEach(obj => console.log('id: ' + obj.id + ' on ' + new Date(obj.date * 1000).toISOString().substr(0,10)));
```

You can do the same thing with local dates, you just need to be a bit more careful of getting the days, see [*How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C448.2885)